# Click event won't register in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, html

Ok, so I'm creating a gallery site for iPad. It needs to be able to swipe and when you click on the thumbnails, it loads the gallery images with AJAX.

The html looks something like this:

```
<section id="col1">
  <nav>
    <div class="appGallery">
      <div class="imageHandler"></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="1.html"><img src="1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="2.html"><img src="2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="3.html"><img src="3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="4.html"><img src="4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

I am using a swipe plugin and basically what the imageHandler does is to track the movement (touch/mouse events). It has a higher z-index that overrides the unordered list so this basically means the 'a' link won't work.

I've written a whole new algorithm to detect which thumbnails is being clicked on $('#col1 nav') based on height and event.pageY. My algorithm works perfectly on desktop but not iPad. The click event just won't register.

Here's how the JavaScript looks like:

```
var dragging = false;

imageHandler.bind('touchmove', function(event) {
  dragging = true;
});

imageHandler.bind('touchend', function(event) {
  var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0]  ||  event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];

  if (dragging) {        
    //swipe column
    dragging = false;
  }
  else {
    //I've done some testing myself by including an alert() here, it pops out.
    $('#col1 nav').click(function(event) {
      //but when I insert and alert() here, nothing happens
      var touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0]  ||  event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];

      //my algorithm to select the thumbnails using touch.pageY
      //ajax using .load
    });
    dragging = false;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're binding it inside the "touchend" event. So click is only registered once you stop dragging.

Have you tried binding it outside the function using a live event? Like so:

```
$('#col1 nav').live("click", function(event) {
```